# Why this if return True in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

`>>> if '' is not None:
...  print'23333'
... 
23333`
I think (not None) is True and ('') is False so why it running print?

Comment: you are checking if `''` is not the same object as `None`, they are not the same object so that check returns True so the condition happens.

Comment: `is not` is the full operator that is happening, try running `if '' is (not None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is` and `is not` test for object identity, i.e., will test if `''` and `None` are the same object, which they are not, so the test returns `True` in your case.

From [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true
>   if and only if x and y are the same object. `x is not y` yields the
>   inverse truth value.

To put it another way, although `''` and `None` have the same ["truthiness"](http://code.maiamccormick.com/blog/2015/04/16/truthiness/), that is they both evaluate to `False` if you do `bool(None)` or `bool('')`, they to do not refer to the same object.

Comment: @dscdtc no problem.This can be confusing at first.

Answer (score 2):

`is not` is a single operator, equal to the negation of `is`. Since `'' is None` is false, `'' is not None` is true.

But since `is` tests *identity*, not equality, `'' is (not None)` still won't do what you want.